# Unable to use a jupyter cell global variable inside a python function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, global-variables

I am working on a jupyter notebook using python

I have created two dataframes like as shown below

The below two dataframes are declared outside the function - Meaning they are just defined/declared/initialized in jupyter notebook cell [And I wish to use them inside a function like as shown below]

```
subcols = ["subjid","marks"]           #written in jupyter cell 1
subjdf= pd.DataFrame(columns=subcols)

testcolumns = ["testid","testmarks"]   #written in jupyter cell 2
testdf= pd.DataFrame(columns=testcolumns)

def fun1():                  #written in jupyter cell 3
....
....
return df1,df2

def fun2(df1,df2):
...
...
return df1,df2,df3

def fun3(df1,df2,df3):
...
  subjdf['subid'] = df1['indid']
...
return df1,df2,df3,subjdf

def fun4(df1,df2,df3,subjdf):
...
  testdf['testid'] = df2['examid']
...
return df1,df2,df3,subjdf,testdf
```

The above way of writing throws an error in `fun3` as below

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'subjdf' referenced before assignment
```

but I have already created `subjdf` outside the function blocks [Refer 1st Jupyter cell]

Two things to note here

a] I don't get an error if I use `global subjdf` in fun3

b] If I use `global subjdf`, I don't get any error for `testdf` in fun4. I was expecting `testdf` to have similar error as well because I have used them the same way in fun4.

So, my question is why not for `testdf` but only for `subjdf`

Additionally, I have followed similar approach earlier [without using global variable but just declaring the df outside the function blocks] and it was working fine. Not sure, why it is throwing error only now.

Can help me to avoid this error? please.

Comment: yes, Mustafa Aydin. You are right. I have done some operations and assigned it to the same name variable. Hence the error. Just figured out with the help of SO user

Answer (score 1):

You have created `subjdf`, but your function `fun3`  needs it as argument :

```
def fun3(subjdf, df1, df2, df3):
  ...
  subjdf['subid'] = df1['indid']
```

You're not using python functions properly. You don't need to use `global` in your case. Whether you pass the correct argument and return it, or think about creating an instance method using `self`. You have many solutions, but Instance methods are a good solution when you have to handle `pandas.Dataframe` within classes and functions.

Comment: But why? why can't it be visible when it is declared outside function - making it visible to all fiunctions.. upvoted for the help

Comment: the same error doesn't happen for testdf

Comment: Am trying to learn. So, you are suggesting that the variables declared outside the functions cannot be used inside the function.. Since they are declared/initialized outside the function, I thought any function can use them. Is my understanding incorrect

Comment: can also help me understand why the same error doesn't happen with `testdf` if I am using it incorrectly

Comment: Visible or not, a python function (especially the way you're using them), cannot take variables outside itself. That is precisely why any function (and not only in Python) takes argument as input.  You clearly have to learn and use the classes in you case : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: No, the same error will happen with `testdf` if your function doesn't have it in its arguments. But of course not. if you'using `global`, but I insist that it's a very bad manner to code. You ruin all the programming logic by doing so.

Comment: exactly. When I use global subjdf, I don't see any error for testdf - from fun4. Hence am confused. Am not using global testdf. So, how come there is no error - which is not surprising because I have followed similar approach earlier as well..and there were no error...am surrpised it throws error for subdf

Comment: I don't have testdf in arguments. If you have time, can I kindly request you try this in jupyter notebook for you to experience it yourself.. So, you can help me understand better

Answer (score 0):

It's possible run you snippet as you guess. So many lines of code is missing.

If you don't want to use a class, and that you want keep using this recursive manner, then rebuild you code that way :

```
subcols = ["subjid","marks"]          
subjdf= pd.DataFrame(columns=subcols)

testcolumns = ["testid","testmarks"]   
testdf= pd.DataFrame(columns=testcolumns)

def fun1():
    # DO SOMETHING to generate df1 and df2
    return df1, df2

def fun2():
    df1, df2 = fun1()
    # DO SOMETHING to generate df3
    return df1, df2, df3

def fun3(subjdf):
    df1, df2, df3 = fun2()
    subjdf['subid'] = df1['indid']
    return df1, df2, df3, subjdf

def fun4(subjdf, testdf):
    df1, df2, df3, subjdf = fun3()
    testdf['testid'] = df2['examid']
    return df1, df2, df3, subjdf, testdf

fun4(subjdf, testdf)
```

But I repeat, build an instance method with `self` for building this.